# Heirarchical Sub-Menu - PHP

Tags: php, treeview, submenu

```
====================================================================
|   menu id    |    parent_id     |   menu            |   Level    |
====================================================================
|    1         |        0         |   Control Panel   |      1     |
====================================================================
|    2         |        1         |   Administrative  |      2     |
====================================================================
|    3         |        2         |   Manage User     |      3     |
====================================================================
|    4         |        2         |   Manage Role     |      3     |
====================================================================
|    5         |        1         |   Change Password |      2     |
====================================================================
```

I have this table to create a sub-menu... the problem is don't know how echo the data and display the echoed data into like this:

```
 - Control Panel
    - Administrative
        - Manage User
        - Manage Role
    - Change Password
```

Does anyone have the answer in PHP? Please I need this solution for my project. Please give me an example. Thank You!

Comment: for future reference, when posting code samples, simply select the code and click on the `{}` icon, or hit CTRL+K

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP recursive menu in HTML list structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213309/php-recursive-menu-in-html-list-structure)

Comment: Voting to close because (a) it is not clear what you're trying to do, and (b) your question doesn't exhibit any effort on your part to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

print lines with level number of spaces or tabs before the text

```
print(getTabs($row['level']).'-'.$row['menu]))
```

Where getTabs returns argument number of tabs/spaces 
Leaving the string format part to you

Answer (score 1):

Your data is already hierarchical - even without the level column, you can build the whole tree. Can you be more specific regarding what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i'm trying to produce a menu that display like a treeview